# RunAs user from administrator account without password?

Tags: windows, runas

Is there a way to `runas /user:<username>` from an administrator account without `runas` prompting for the user's password?

Comment: No; The same way its not possible to use the sudo command without providing a password;

Comment: That's not true.  Root can run a sudo command as a user without getting prompted for the user's password.  I just tried it.

Comment: Please provide the command you used.  I was more like indicating that a non-root user would need to provide the root password when they issued a sudo command.  My statement was brief since it was a comment.

Comment: Yes, trying to elevate privileges should always ask for a password, but that's not what I'm asking to do here.  I'm asking about using the `runas` command from an administrator account to run a command as a non-privileged account.  It doesn't matter what command.

Comment: Do you know the password and you want to just not have to type it? Or do you not know it at all? I think admin users can not do `runas` until they know the password. They can reset the user's password but there is not a way to find out what it is if you don't already know.

Comment: @KevinPanko no i don't know their password. When I've used runas before, it asks for a password.

Comment: I'm not sure about regular administrator privileges, but Windows has a super-administrator account (must be activated; disabled by default).  With that, you don't need passwords or even Runas; you can just do whatever you want because you basically own everything and every user.  It is intended only for temporary use for administrative tasks.